# grub rescue after deleting and extending linux partition

Tags: grubrescue

I want to go back to booting from windows only. I have however deleted and merged the initial linux partition. problem is, while intending to fix grub via bootrec /fixmbr etc, I need to get past grub rescue even if I have a recovery media with wjndows 10. Either way, i need to get rid of rescue grab first.

Comment: Windows (of any version) has always turned out to be very possessive in regard to the MBR. You can use the original installation DVD to get to a _Windows Rescue Prompt_. Then execute `bootrec /fixmbr` or something like this and Windows will handle the "rest".

Comment: As i mentioned, I have the windows installation files ready bt still need to go through the grub rescue. That is the hurdle

Comment: If you have the recovery media, just booting from it will bypass grub, which is installed on your HDD, so you are still booting from it, not your media (cd/dvd?)

Comment: my recovery media is a usb stick. I tried booting from it but it still takes me to grub first. That is the problem. Or did I do anything wrong? I prepped the usb using rufus

Comment: turns out the USb had not been formatted correctly to become bootable. I redid it again and now it works